# Python 3 - Working with datetime.time objects - timedelta

Tags: python, django, datetime, python-3.x, time

Just got a problem I don't understand in my python code.

```
timestamps = list(map(lambda ts: ts.time, timestamps))
start_timestamps = timestamps
end_timestamps = timestamps[1:]
d = date(2000, 1, 1)
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
for i, t1 in enumerate(start_timestamps):
    t1 = datetime.combine(d, start_timestamps[i])
    t2 = datetime.combine(d, end_timestamps[i])
    dt = t1 - t2
    #dt = datetime.strptime(t1,FMT) - datetime.strptime(t2,FMT)
```

By using this in my django project I get the following error:

```
t2 = datetime.combine(d, end_timestamps[i])
```

> TypeError: combine() argument 2 must be datetime.time, not bytes

When uncommenting the last line und commenting the three lines above it, I'm getting the following:

```
dt = datetime.strptime(t1,FMT) - datetime.strptime(t2,FMT)
```

> TypeError: must be str, not datetime.time

So I really don't understand it. It is `datetime.time`, but the same time it is not ... Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Some** of your objects are `bytes` objects, and others are `datetime.time` objects. In other words, you have a mix of objects.

Note that it was `end_timestamps[i]` that failed, not `start_timestamps[i]`, in your first error. Ergo, `start_timestamps[i]` was a `time` object. If all objects in `timestamps` where `bytes` objects, `datetime.combine(d, start_timestamps[i])` would have failed.

You need to figure out why your `ts.time()` calls in your `map()` call return inconsistent data types.

Comment: Thanks, I just didn't saw this. I have another line which is appending a time to the list in end_timestamps and it ist delivered by a function returning a time-object. But I don't get it to convert it to an datetime.time object. Can you help me?

Comment: No, not really. If you posted a new question with a [mcve] illustrating the issue I could, perhaps, as then I'd have enough information to be of help. :-)